# Javascript: how to append more text to user copied text ala nydailynews.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On [nydailynews.com](http://nydailynews.com) when you copy and paste any text from the site, a snippet of text is appended.

> Read more: http://www.nydailynews.com/#ixzz0aN123abc

**How do they achieve this?**

I have searched all of the external JavaScript files (jquery) and can't seem to find anything that corresponds. Is this something that could be done in simple css?

Comment: Ok i disabled javascript and well it doesn't work after that so it's jquery.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me, script or no.

Comment: Yea it depends on what you copy, if you go to a article it does it with the body text but not the title, and it only does it with some of the elements on the front page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [EventBug](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/category/eventbug/) in Firefox, you'll see that a [copy](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html) event fires. The JS on the page is listening for this event and changing the clipboard contents. There are so many files loaded by that page it's hard to find the source code, though.

Comment: okie I'm dumb, http://www.tynt.com/ is the service it is using, will have to see if it's something i can't replicate. I thank you for the lead cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to add extra text to the copied content

Source : http://bavotasan.com/2010/add-a-copyright-notice-to-copied-text/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addLink() {
var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var selection;
selection = window.getSelection();
var pagelink = "<br /><br /> Read more at: <a href='"+document.location.href+"'>"+document.location.href+"</a><br />Copyright &copy; c.bavota"; // change this if you want
var copytext = selection + pagelink;
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.style.position='absolute';
newdiv.style.left='-99999px';
body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
},0);
}
document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>
```